# Is it possible to have a compile-time "reference" to a variable?

Tags: c++, optimization, reference

Consider the following code:

```
Matrix4x4 perspective(const ViewFrustum &frustum) {
    float l = frustum.l;
    float r = frustum.r;
    float b = frustum.b;
    float t = frustum.t;
    float n = frustum.n;
    float f = frustum.f;

    return {
        { 2 * n / (r - l), 0,               (r + l) / (r - l),    0                      },
        { 0,               2 * n / (t - b), (t + b) / (t - b),    0                      },
        { 0,               0,               -((f + n) / (f - n)), -(2 * n * f / (f - n)) },
        { 0,               0,               -1,                   0                      }
    };
}
```

In order to improve readability of constructing the matrix, I have to either make a copy of values from the frustum struct, or references to them. However, neither do I actually need copies or indirection.

Is it possible to have some kind of a "reference" that would be resolved at compile time, kind of like a symbolic link. It would have the same effect as:

```
Matrix4x4 perspective(const ViewFrustum &frustum) {
    #define l frustum.l;
    #define r frustum.r;
    #define b frustum.b;
    #define t frustum.t;
    #define n frustum.n;
    #define f frustum.f;

    return {
        { 2 * n / (r - l), 0,               (r + l) / (r - l),    0                      },
        { 0,               2 * n / (t - b), (t + b) / (t - b),    0                      },
        { 0,               0,               -((f + n) / (f - n)), -(2 * n * f / (f - n)) },
        { 0,               0,               -1,                   0                      }
    };

    #undef l
    #undef r
    #undef b
    #undef t
    #undef n
    #undef f
}
```

Without the preprocessor (or is it acceptable?). I suppose it isn't really needed, or could be avoided in this particular case by making those 6 values arguments to a function directly (though it would be a bit irritating having to call the function like that - but even then, I could make an inline proxy function).

But I was just wondering if this is somehow possible in general? I could not find anything like it. I think it would come in handy for locally shortening descriptive names that are going to be used a lot, without actually having to lose the original names.

Comment: You mean like a reference?  `float& l(frustum.l)` etc ?

Comment: @John3136 yes, but the actual reference isn't needed

Comment: Either way you look at it, it is entirely a micro-optimization, whether you make a copy or use a reference. The compiler is smart enough to optimize references to those variables. Do what is best for readability.

Comment: @Byteventurer What do you mean it isn't needed? You're the one asking for it!

Comment: @John3136 I mean I don't need it at runtime

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Alright I see, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Obligatory disclaimer***: do not prematurely optimize.

Let me compare your naive `perspective` function, containing

```
float l = frustum.l;
float r = frustum.r;
float b = frustum.b;
float t = frustum.t;
float n = frustum.n;
float f = frustum.f;
```

With `define`'s and @Sam Varshavchik solution with references.

We assume that our compiler is optimizing, and optimizing at least decent.

Assembly output for all three versions: https://godbolt.org/g/G06Bx8.

You can notice that reference and define versions are exactly the same - as expected. But naive differs a lot. It first loads all the values from memory:

```
    movss   (%rdi), %xmm2           # xmm2 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   4(%rdi), %xmm1          # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   8(%rdi), %xmm0          # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   %xmm0, 12(%rsp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movss   12(%rdi), %xmm0         # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)          # 4-byte Spill
    movss   16(%rdi), %xmm3         # xmm3 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movaps  %xmm3, 16(%rsp)         # 16-byte Spill
    movss   20(%rdi), %xmm0
```

And then never again references the `%rdi` (`frustrum`) memory. Reference and define versions, on the other hand, load values as they are needed.

This happens because the implementation of `Vector4` constructor is hidden from the optimizer and it can't assume that constructor doesn't modify `frustrum`, so it **must** insert loads, even when such loads are redundant.

So, naive version can be even *faster* than "optimized" one, under certain circumstances.

Comment: @Byteventurer, as for `clang`, they do not became the same, but compiler doesn't reload values from memory every time anymore: https://godbolt.org/g/hQfASp. So it's better and (I think) will be as fast as naive at runtime.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! :D (for the record, as I deleted the comment - I asked if it makes a difference if matrix is implemented as plain array)

Comment: @Byteventurer: Hopefully you have trivial functions like these constructors defined in headers, unlike Deniss's example.  Link-time optimization can fix this, but it's a bad idea to have trivial functions that aren't visible at compile time.  Compilers can't assume much about what a function could have modified if they can't see the definition, but if they can see it, they can find out exactly what a function does even if it isn't inlined.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, these are in the header file as they are actually templated. Thanks for the tip though, I don't usually do that, but I guess I should. :)

Answer (score 14):

Well, that's what C++ references are for:

```
const float &l = frustum.l;
const float &r = frustum.r;
const float &b = frustum.b;
const float &t = frustum.t;
const float &n = frustum.n;
const float &f = frustum.f;
```

Most modern compilers will optimize out the references, and use the values from the `frustum` object verbatim, in the following expression, by resolving the references at compile-time.

Comment: Will the compiler also optimize the variables out if they aren't references - just copies?

Comment: I see, so the references will not actually be used? No indirection?

Comment: Your code won't compile unless you `const` qualify your float references (`frustum` is const).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Most likely, yes. You can confirm whether this is the case by checking the emitted assembly.

Answer (score 4):

*In general*, you can use plain references, as long as you are in the local scope. Modern compilers "see through them" and just treat them as aliases (notice that this actually applies even to pointers).

However, when dealing with stuff on the small side, copying to a local variable, if anything, is generally beneficial. `frustnum.r`is one layer of indirection away (`frustnum` is actually a pointer under the hood), so accessing it is costlier than it may seem, and if you have function calls in the middle of your function the compiler may not be able to prove that its value isn't changing, so the access may need to be repeated.

Local variables instead are normally directly on the stack (cheap) or straight in registers (cheapest), and, most importantly, given that they usually have no interaction with "the outside", the compiler has an easier time reasoning about them, so it can be more aggressive with optimizations; also, when actually performing the computations those values are going to be copied in registers and on the stack anyway.

So go ahead and use copies, at worst the compiler will probably do the same, at best you may helped it optimizing stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I wasn't sure, thanks :)